# Not able to test RefundTransaction API (Classic) on Paypal API Explorer

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I tried to use Paypal API Explorer to know how the refund transaction works. I have put all the API credentials as required like-

- API username : mail.to.test8_api1.gmail.com
- API password : 1377073507
- API signature : A31HItFbi5O6W1s3eD0VWuU5g27BAIkTTYOmDy9y1mr83sXDepHmc1yr
- Application ID (sandbox) : APP-80W284485P519543T
- currencyCode : AUD
- errorLanguage : en_US
- detailLevel : returnAll
- transactionId : 56M95729K97884456
- amount : 10.0
- email : mail.to.test8@gmail.com
- primary(true)

and I hit 'Try Now' button. It processed my request and gave response as

- ack: Failure
- errorId: 520002
- message: Internal Error
- correlationId: e3df5c7dbd58b

But I don't understand, why did it fail ? Am I doing anything wrong ?
Or do I need to provide any more information ?

Comment: You will probably need to post the actual data you tried for someone to be able to troubleshoot your problem. What's the corelation id that you see in the response?

Comment: @aydiv : I have adited my question and have put all the value as well as correlationId